# How to match elements of a list with different length substrings of a string?

Tags: python

I have done some coding and here it goes:

```
s='hello world'
lst=['he','hel','wor']
i=0
for ch in lst:
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i:i+len(ch)]==ch:
            contains=True            

        else:
            contains=False

        i+=1
print(contains)
```

and I am not getting the right return. Could someone please take a look and give me some pointers please? Thanks

Comment: Consider this: if `contains` is `False` in one iteration, it can become `True` in the next. But is that really possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
contains = all(sub in s for sub in lst)
```

`[sub in s for sub in lst]` is a list comprehension that has the value `sub in s` for every element `sub` in `lst`. Basically, it returns a `True` for every element in `s` that's present in `lst`, and a `False` for every element that's NOT present in `lst`. `all()` is a function that only returns `True` if ALL elements in the iterable you pass it are truthy. Compare with `any()` which returns `True` if ANY element in its iterable is truthy, e.g. you could do `contains = not any(sub not in s for sub in lst)`

Comment: This is really good. I didn't know about this. Thanks for this neat way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are certainly several ways to make it shorter, but here is the modification of your program which should work:

```
s = 'hello world'
lst = ['he','rld','wor']
i = 0
containsall = True

for ch in lst:
    contains = False
    for i in range(len(s) - len(ch) + 1):
        if s[i:i+len(ch)] == ch:
            contains = True            
            break

    if not contains:
       containsall = False
       break

print(containsall)
```

Basically, as soon as a string found in a word, we break and go to the next word. Otherwise, this string is not in `s` and we don't need to check the remaining words and we break out of the main loop. If all the substrings have passed with 'contains`being True, we never get to`containsall = False` and so it is True overall; otherwise, it will return False.

Comment: This is a more detailed way to do the same thing. Thanks for working on the problem.